# Parsing data stored in URLs via BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to access the URLs of the different fish family from this website: http://www.fishbase.org/ComNames/CommonNameSearchList.php?CommonName=Salmon

I'd like to be able to run a script that opens the links of the given website to then be able to parse the information stored within the pages. I'm fairly new to web scraping, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

This is what I have so far:

```
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

fish_url = 'http://www.fishbase.org/ComNames/CommonNameSearchList.php?CommonName=Salmon'
page = urllib2.urlopen(fish_url)
html_doc = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.fishbase.org/ComNames/CommonNameSearchList.php?CommonName=Salmon').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
for fish in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    print fish['href']
```

Answer (score 3):

Scrapy is the perfect tool for this.  It is a python web scraping framework.
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

You can pass in your url with you term, and create rules for crawling.

FOr example using a regex you would add a rule to scrape all links with the path `/Summary` and then extract the information using XPath or Beautiful soup.

Additionally you can set up a rule to automatically handle the pagination, ie in your example url it could automatically follow the Next link.

Basically a lot of what you are trying to do comes packaged for free in scrapy.  I would def take a look into it.

Comment: Is there any open source Web Scraping framework for Python 3.x?  Scrapy is only for 2.7..

Comment: @Erik Check out [BeautifulSoup](crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Thanks Steinar , I ended up moving out of Python completely.. Now utilize CasperJS and PhantomJS.  It's native DOM tree traversal really sped things up.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just writing a one-off script to grab all the data from this site, you can do something like:

```
fish_url_base = "http://www.fishbase.org/ComNames/%s"
fish_urls = [fish_url_base%a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a')]
```

This gives you a list of links to traverse, which you can pass to `urllib2.urlopen` and `BeautifulSoup`:

```
for url in fish_urls:
    fish_soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    # Do something with your fish_soup
```

(Note 1: I haven't tested this code; you might need to adjust the base URL to fit the `href` attributes so you get to the right site.)

(Note 2: I see you're using `bs4` but calling `findAll` on the soup. `findAll` was right for BS3, but it is changed to `find_all` in `bs4`.)

(Note 3: If you're doing this for practical rather than learning purposes / fun, there are more efficient ways of scraping, such as `scrapy` also mentioned here.)